# IOS 10 Multipeer

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

Is Multipeer working on iOS 10? We are using it on Wifi and once in a while receive unable to connect error message and after that the devices won't connect. We need to restart the app for them to connect again. This is almost a showstopper bug for our project since as soon as this error occurs the application stops working and the devices won't connect at all. We are using the latest iOS 10.2. Please let us know in case there is any workaround for this issue. Any help is much appreciated.

```
2016-12-23 08:31:27.980778 RestKit[313:14524] [MCNearbyServiceBrowser] Peer [central,40A4EC6F] error in connectedHandler [Unable to connect].
2016-12-23 08:31:27.982179 RestKit[313:14524] [MCNearbyServiceBrowser] Peer [central,40A4EC6F] error in connectedHandler [Unable to connect].
2016-12-23 08:31:27.985532 RestKit[313:14524] [MCNearbyServiceBrowser] Peer [central,40A4EC6F] error in connectedHandler [Unable to connect].
2016-12-23 08:31:27.986003 RestKit[313:14524] [MCNearbyServiceBrowser] Peer [central,40A4EC6F] error in connectedHandler [Unable to connect].
2016-12-23 08:31:27.986351 RestKit[313:14524] [MCNearbyServiceBrowser] Peer [central,40A4EC6F] error in connectedHandler [Unable to connect].
2016-12-23 08:31:28.373599 RestKit[313:19758] disconnected to central
2016-12-23 08:31:29.440309 RestKit[313:14524] [MCNearbyServiceBrowser] Peer [central,40A4EC6F] error in connectedHandler [Unable to connect].
```

Answer (score 0):

it works fine with this version no probem found.

Mario

Comment: If you watch the console while Multipeer is running, however, it will report a bunch of connection errors which can be disconcerting to someone unfamiliar with the framework. They are a normal part of how Multipeer continuously negotiates ad-hoc bluetooth/wifi network connections.

Answer (score 0):

Multipeer will often report connection outages, but continue to work as advertised. This has been true since long before iOS 10, and is the price of working with an abstracted high-end framework which hides the implementation details of bluetooth, Bonjour and peer-to-peer networking which are all used under the hood.

If you want more fine-grained control, you can always use lower-level frameworks and manage the networking issues yourself.